# Add icon left side of div

Tags: html, css

So this is how my project currently looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f10f36656a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.feedcard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #7F0008;
  margin: 5px;
  
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.feed-avatar {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display:inline;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #446C74;
  margin: 5px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.title, .sub-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
}
.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sub-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}

.boxcontent {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- <img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png"> -->

<div id="main-container">

  <div class="feedcard">
    
    <div class="mainbox">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">NAME HERE</p>
      <p class="sub-title" style="color:rgb(128,128,128);">Team 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxcontent">
      <div class="sale">
        <text style="color:rgb(76, 175, 80);font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;">PP Test 30%</text>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:left;">
        <form method="post" action="kudos.php" id="myForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ident" value="<?php echo $myIdent ?>">
          <text style="color:rgb(128,128,128);font-size: 16px;" class="fas fa-heart">&nbsp;0</text>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:right;">
        23 minutes ago
      </div>
    </div> <!-- buttons -->
  </div> <!-- boxcontent -->
  </div> <!-- buttons -->
</div> <!-- feedcard -->

</div> <!-- main-container -->


</body>
</html>
```

And this is basically what I want it to look like:
[image: Image here]

So basically, what I want is to split up the div, and where the X is in the image I want to have a small icon (on the left side there). I tried split using `float left`, and `float right`, but can't make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: try to use flexbox to align 2 boxes next to each other instead of using float (wrong tool here. Is a mis-used hack from before 2013 as you had no flexbox nor css-grid by then)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f10f36656a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>

body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
div#main-container { /* flex css */
    display: flex;
}
.closeBtn { /*left side btn css */
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}
.feedcard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #7F0008;
  margin: 5px;
  
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.feed-avatar {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display:inline;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #446C74;
  margin: 5px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.title, .sub-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
}
.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sub-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}

.boxcontent {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- <img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png"> -->

<div id="main-container">
 <div class="closeBtn">X</div> <!-- ADD here X btn -->

  <div class="feedcard">
    
    <div class="mainbox">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">NAME HERE</p>
      <p class="sub-title" style="color:rgb(128,128,128);">Team 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxcontent">
      <div class="sale">
        <text style="color:rgb(76, 175, 80);font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;">PP Test 30%</text>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:left;">
        <form method="post" action="kudos.php" id="myForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ident" value="<?php echo $myIdent ?>">
          <text style="color:rgb(128,128,128);font-size: 16px;" class="fas fa-heart">&nbsp;0</text>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:right;">
        23 minutes ago
      </div>
    </div> <!-- buttons -->
  </div> <!-- boxcontent -->
  </div> <!-- buttons -->
</div> <!-- feedcard -->

</div> <!-- main-container -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: downvoted for following reasons: Missing explanation of the issue and solution. Anwser only containing codelines without sufficient explanations of it can eb considered low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` you can achieve this

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.feedcard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid #7F0008;
  margin: 5px;
  
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.feed-avatar {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display:inline;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #446C74;
  margin: 5px;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.title, .sub-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
}
.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sub-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F3F3F;
}

.boxcontent {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top:10px;
}
.flex{
display: flex;
align-items:center;/*play with this to align picture to box*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f10f36656a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="flex">

<img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png"> 


  <div class="feedcard">
    
    <div class="mainbox">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="feed-avatar" src="img_avatar.png">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">NAME HERE</p>
      <p class="sub-title" style="color:rgb(128,128,128);">Team 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxcontent">
      <div class="sale">
        <text style="color:rgb(76, 175, 80);font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;">PP Test 30%</text>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:left;">
        <form method="post" action="kudos.php" id="myForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_ident" value="<?php echo $myIdent ?>">
          <text style="color:rgb(128,128,128);font-size: 16px;" class="fas fa-heart">&nbsp;0</text>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="actionbuttons" style="float:right;">
        23 minutes ago
      </div>
    </div> <!-- buttons -->
  </div> <!-- boxcontent -->
  </div> <!-- buttons -->
</div> <!-- feedcard -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```